# Uploading picture via REST API

Tags: rest-api

I have picture URL like `http://cdn.action.pl/File.aspx?CID=73191&UID=jani1903&PID=115d9055a5d14aeacec6ecbb1484714f&P=/Pictures/KSL/SON/KSL/KSLSONKSL0059/29X0c3F9t0I051R5P7Q5u8K8k1A3O0s1.jpg`

I'm trying make product with that pic, but REST API say it's the wrong format and it's not acceptable due to security.

What can I do? Reformat it via PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by downloading first those picture via exec(wget).